# Is "which may causes" the correct phrase?

Tags: modal-verbs, verb-forms, modality

I'm just practicing passage reconstruction. Here I've formed a phrase "*Organic former usually use natural pesticides and fertilizers instead using chemical pesticide **which may causes** economic damage to agricultural productivity.*" for respective phrase from a passage "*Organic farmers use natural pesticides and fertilizers.*". I've used "**which may causes**" to form the phrase. Is this correct?

Comment: There are too many errors in the sentence you wrote to be addressed in a single question. The correct form of the phrase in bold is _"which may **cause**."_ The modal verb _may_ takes the _infinitive_ here. Can you tell us whether you know what a _modal verb_ is in English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be confusing

> **which causes** economic damage to agricultural productivity.

and

> **may cause** economic damage to agricultural productivity.

which as @P.E.Dant points out uses a *modal verb*.

Comment: Thank you. Now i understand...  I appreciate your help.. Thanks @P.E.Dant